# somebody can help me to merge this two php functions?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this two functions:

this function generate a ul li tree menu from mysql
parent, parentid, title

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
$data[$row->ParentId][] = $row;
}

function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0) {
static $i = 1;
//$tab = str_repeat('-', $i);
if ($data[$parent]) {
    $html .= "\n<ul" . ($parent == 0 ? ' class="tree"' : '') . ">\n";
    $i++;
    foreach ($data[$parent] as $v) {
        $child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent);
        $html .= "<li>";
        $html .= '<span>' . $v->Title . "</span>";
        if ($child) {
            $i–;
            $html .= $child;
        }
        $html .= "</li>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>\n";
    return $html;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

echo (BuildTree($data));
```

it generate a menu like:

category A
-subcategory of category A
--sub category A of sub category A
category B
......infinite...

and this function get the keys of an array

```
function GetKeys($array, $tree = array()) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        GetKeys($value, array_merge($tree, array($key)));
    } else {
        print implode('.', array_merge($tree, array($key, $value)));
        print "\n<br />";
    }
}
}

GetKeys($data);
```

it get the keys like

0
01
001
020
for each child of the menu

but i dont know how to merge it to get something like:

category A [0]
-subcategory of category A [00]
--sub category A of sub category A [000]
--sub category B of category A [001]
category B [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKa4l.png)
 infinite...

can somebody help me with this problem i have?

the $var_dump of $data get:

[array structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKa4l.png)

[complete code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVvm9.png)

THE SOLUTION:

```
function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0, $k=false) {
static $i = 1;
if ($data[$parent]) {
$html .= "\n<ul" . ($parent == 0 ? ' class="tree"' : '') . ">\n";
$i++;
foreach ($data[$parent] as $key => $v) {
$child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent, $k.$key);
$html .= "<li>[" . $k.$key . ']';
$html .= '<span>' . $v->Title . "</span>";
if ($child) {
    $i–;
    $html .= $child;
}
$html .= "</li>\n";
}
$html .= "</ul>\n";
return $html;
} else {
return false;
}
}

echo (BuildTree($data));
```

people who help in it:

the-breaker
Amr Berag

THANKS!

Comment: In your `BuildTree` function can you simply access `$v->Code` or similar? Show us what a few elements of `$data` looks like.

Comment: Make an effort to merge them yourself, and come back here when you've done so and run into a specific problem, and ask a specific question about that problem. If you can't make that effort yourself, hire a contractor to do the work for you.

Comment: im with it like 5 days, i try ways, but i dont know, im blocked, the $data var is an array of the info db, example, title, parent, parentid, sorry for my bad english, i cant find anything in spanish, so im trying here

Comment: Does (or could) the `$data` array contain the "key"? It is not at all clear how `$array` and `$data` differ. Or is the "key" derived only when you render the tree? Also. para que se educe: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Not knowing the structure it really might be as simple as `foreach ($data[$parent] as $key => $v) {`

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Getkeys function to return a sorted array of keys then make it global and access it from your BuildTree() function and every time add the first element in the keys before closing li and immediately remove it using unset. the concept is to think of the tree as a linear thing. Here is my try:

```
$g_keys = array();
function GetKeys($array, $tree = array()) {
global $g_keys;//global
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        GetKeys($value, array_merge($tree, array($key)));
    } else {
        $k = implode('.', array_merge($tree, array($key, $value)));
        $g_keys[]=$k;
    }
}

}


function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0) {

 global $g_keys;//global


static $i = 1;
//$tab = str_repeat('-', $i);
if ($data[$parent]) {
    $html .= "\n<ul" . ($parent == 0 ? ' class="tree"' : '') . ">\n";
    $i++;
    foreach ($data[$parent] as $v) {
        $child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent);
        $html .= "<li>";
        $html .= '<span>' . $v->Title . "</span>";
        if ($child) {
            $i–;
            $html .= $child;
        }
        $html .="[".array_shift($g_keys)."]</li>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>\n";
    return $html;
} else {
    return false;
}
}


  //Now use it 

GetKeys($data);// $g_keys is a global that can be accessed from both functions now
echo (BuildTree($data));
```

**.............................**

**array_shift()**
*This is my first time using this function. this is what the docs telling about it.(if its not working try doing it manually)*

> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
>   shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All
>   numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero
>   while literal keys won't be touched.

Comment: this is not tested and composed using mobile device but should work

Comment: i try but it dont show anything, but when i comment the function GetKeys($data), or change the name of var $data to $xxx it work and show the just the tree structure

Comment: inside the function BuildTree(), i add the global var $keys

Comment: i try var_dump($keys) but dont show anything, but if i try keys = GetKey($data); var_dump($keys) again it show a blank document again

Comment: no outside. I only added three lines to your code, the rest is just the arrangment

Comment: i add the picture of the entire code because i dont know how put here formatted

Comment: i edited my answer try again .Please understand the concept first so you can modify it since i didn't test it